# Echo array rows into textareas when clicking on select's option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm retrieving an array filled with data from the database.
I want to build a dropdown filled with all names, and when clicking in one name, I want to echo the values into some textarea I have in a form.
like this:

```
array 
  0 => 
    array 
      'id' 
      'name'
      'desc' 
      'date'
  1 => 
    array 
      'id'
      'name'
      'desc' 
      'date'
```

this would be my code:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
       <select>
          <?php some foreach that fills the dropdown ?>
       </select>

    <input type="text" id="nombre" name="name">
    <input type="text" id="dato" name="date">        
    <textarea id="desc" name="desc"><?php echo ...></textarea>


    <input class="cbp-mc-submit" type="submit" value="publish" />

    </form>

       <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>


       <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So how did you try this? where is your code?

Comment: Then you need to convert the array into JSON so that JavaScript can use it.  It obviously won't use `echo` which is a PHP command.

Comment: *I want to build a dropdown...*, *I want to echo the values into some textarea...*, do these things first, then come back if you need help.

Comment: I've added my code. Anyway, I need Javascript to fill the textboxes when clicking on the dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are okay with populating the dropdown via PHP. Here is how you grab the selected option's value (or the text) and plop it into the textarea:

```js
$('#selID').change(function(){

  $('#taID').val( this.value );
  //or
  //$('#taID').val( $(this).find(':selected').text() );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selID">
  <option value="">Choose One</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi Automobile</option>
  <option value="burger">Deluxe Hamburger</option>
  <option value="bunnie">Peter Rabbit</option>
</select>
<br>
<textarea id="taID" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
```

---

Notes:

`this` refers to the element that triggered the javascript - in this case, the `<select>` control's change event triggered the js.

In pure javascript, `this.value` returns the value of the element. However, if you need to run further jQuery operations (such as `.find()` or `.text()`) then you need to return a jQuery object for those operations to operate on. In that case, use `$(this)`.

Since `this.value` is faster to type than `$(this).val()`, I used the pure js method when I didn't need to create a jQuery object. I often use the same shortcut when I just need to get the ID of an element, such as:

```
var myID = this.id;
```

Comment: I will try this. Thank you!

Comment: I added a bit more explanation. Probably you already know these things, but thought I would mention just in case something is helpful...

Comment: It worked just fine! Now I'm having new issues because, I'm populating only the ID of my global array. I need to echo for example MyArray =>
                SubArray (ID=1)=> Name ="Peter";

in: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /> and the value inside the input to be "Peter".

Comment: I tried something like this:

<script type="text/javascript"> 
                 
                  $('#selID').change(function(){
                  $('#name').val($Array[this.value]["name"];);
                  });
                   </script>
Where this.value would be the Array's position inside the Array in order to get my "name" value from that Array position. 
Did you followed me?

Comment: Hmmm. Nothing immediately leaps to mind. Suggest that you close this question (by checkmarking a correct answer) and open a new question for that one. That way you'll have dozens of new eyes trying to help, instead of waiting on me to sign in to SO again tomorrow. *Bon Chance*

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your output to a json_encode() and using the below code block you can receive it.

```
$("#selectID").on('change', function() {
  var sid = $('select[name=select]').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "/get/data",
    data: {sid:sid},
    type: "POST",
    dataType : "json",
    success: function(xhr){
      $('#desc').val(xhr);
    });
  }
 });   
});
```